# How do I logically deliver content from the database once per month

Tags: database, events, subscription

I am building a subscription service that delivers one **personalized** story to users each month. How do I ensure that this trigger happens for each existing user and they don't get the same story twice. Here are my database schema tables.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a `UserStoryLink` Table.
This will have the following Columns - > `Id`/`UserId`(Foreign to User)/ `StoryId`(Foreign to UserStoy)

On each personalized story send, update `UserStoryLink` with the `UserId` and `StoryId`.
You can then, before sending, check that `StoryId` is never present where `UserId` of who you're sending it to is present.